# How to capture an SSL GET request with FiddleCore

Tags: c#, proxy-server, fiddlercore

I'm trying to get the full HTTPS url for each request.
So far I'm getting only a CONNECT request with the domain url

How can I get the full URL request?

This is my code so far

```
Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest += FiddlerApplication_BeforeRequest;
Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.BeforeResponse += FiddlerApplication_BeforeResponse;


if (!Fiddler.CertMaker.rootCertExists())
{
   if (!Fiddler.CertMaker.createRootCert())
   {
       throw new Exception("Unable to create cert for FiddlerCore.");
   }
}

if (!Fiddler.CertMaker.rootCertIsTrusted())
{
   if (!Fiddler.CertMaker.trustRootCert())
   {
      throw new Exception("Unable to install FiddlerCore's cert.");
   }
}

Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup(0,
            FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default |
            FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.AllowRemoteClients |
            FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.DecryptSSL |
            FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.MonitorAllConnections |
            FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.RegisterAsSystemProxy |
            FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.ChainToUpstreamGateway |
            FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.CaptureLocalhostTraffic);



void FiddlerApplication_BeforeResponse(Session oSession)
{
        if (oSession.uriContains("youtube"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Osession.fullUrl());
        }
}

void FiddlerApplication_BeforeRequest(Session oSession)
{
        if (oSession.uriContains("youtube"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Osession.fullUrl());
            oSession.bBufferResponse = true;
        }
}
```

With the browser help I'm trying to reach https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-gzrWQO7VI URL. Can the fiddler catch it?

Thanks a million.
Ran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, Fiddler can capture this. If you're *only* seeing the CONNECT that implies that the client isn't trusting Fiddler's certificate. You should put back the lines that log notifications and errors; my guess is that you'll see one noting that `makecert.exe` isn't where it belongs.

Your code above will not compile since `OSession` isn't the same as `oSession`.

Comment: Yes, yes, yes.
Its the makecert. You are amazing. Thank you so much!!

Comment: I thought that putting the dll's CertMaker, BCMakeCert is enough.

Comment: If you want to use CertMaker.dll/BCMakeCert.dll, you need to have them in the correct location and the right versions matching FiddlerCore's .NET version.